# Why is my MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem always using plain style on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios6, mapkit, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I'm adding a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` to a toolbar. This works fine on iPhone, but on iPad the button will only use the "plain" style. This makes it almost invisible on a black toolbar, so I want to use the bordered style. But even setting the item's `style` property to `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` makes no difference - it always renders on iPad as if using `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`

For completeness, this is the code I use to add the button:

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *userTrackingButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithMapView:self.mapView];
NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self toolbar] items]];
[toolbarItems insertObject:userTrackingButton atIndex:0];
[self.toolbar setItems:toolbarItems];
```

Here's how it looks on iPhone (right):

[image: iPhone example]

And on iPad (wrong):

[image: iPad example]

Tested on iOS 6.1, with a plain UIToolbar. I know UIToolbar on iPad can show bordered toolbar items, because it works for normal buttons, like this one, but I just can't get the user tracking button to do the same:

[image]

Comment: Good question.. Does nomebody knows an answer? :)

Comment: I filed rdar://[13331434](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2821401) for this issue.

Comment: Did you find a work around by any chance?

Comment: How can you set this button without border on iPhone ? (…)